# Parsing a website running locally in a browser?

Tags: python, html, node.js

Is there a way with node.js or with python, to parse a website that is up locally on my computer? For example every second I want it to view updates on a website and do things with that data.

I know about web scraping, but this website contains private data (protected by a login), and has no API. I am logged into the website and can see the data as it streams in real time, I just need a way to parse it.

Comment: When you say "up locally on my computer", do you mean that the actual *server* is running on your computer, or do you just mean you have it open in a browser?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I have the website running in a browser -- I control nothing with the server the website is on

Comment: You can use this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-data-behind-site-logins-with-python-ee0676f523ee